# Keycloak SSO with SAML via webservice call/java api

Tags: java, security, single-sign-on, saml, keycloak

I'm currently working on a keycloak client to authentificate the user with SAML 2.0.
Instead of redirecting the user to the login page, we want to authentificate the user directly over a webservice call or a java client/java api.

It is possible to login the user into a saml keycloak client by using a keycloak service api?

Does the keycloak offer a security token service?

What we already tried:

- Using the [java client](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/authz/client/src/main/java/org/keycloak/authorization/client/AuthzClient.java) to login - it worked with a openid-connect client, but not with a saml client
- Searched the [documentation](http://www.keycloak.org/documentation.html) for either an saml java api or a SecurityTokenService

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Hey @Xevak, I am trying to do same thing i.e. SSO via rest API. If you can share some link or github project, will be highly helpful to me.